# Weak convergence on $C[0,\infty)$.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, weak-convergence

In [Billingslys convergences of probability measures](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471197459) he talks about weak convergence on $C[0,1]$, and later on $D$.

Are there any books that talk about weak convergence on $C[0,\infty)$ equipped with for instance the metric which gives convergence when we have uniform convergence on compact sets?